why rgb color value changing but background color is not changing
upon clicking the div the background color of div should changes as per the selected type of color either rgb or hex color mode but the problem is when type of color is hex ,things go perfectly fine, chnages the backgroud color randomly on clicking the div but on clicking rgb button rgb color value changes but background color dont change.

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default  function RandomColor() {

    const [typeOfColor, setTypeOfColor] = useState('rgb')
    const [color, setColor] = useState('#000000')

    

    function randomColorUtility(length) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
    }



    function handleCreateRandomHexColor() {
        const hex = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
        let hexColor = "#";

        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            hexColor += hex[(randomColorUtility(hex.length))]
        }
        
        setColor(hexColor);
    }

    function handleCreateRandomRGBColor() {
        let r = randomColorUtility(256);
        let g = randomColorUtility(256);
        let b = randomColorUtility(256);
        setColor(`(${r},${g}, ${b})`);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeOfColor === "rgb") handleCreateRandomRGBColor();
        else handleCreateRandomHexColor();
      }, [typeOfColor]);
    



    

    return (
        <div   onClick={
            typeOfColor === "hex"
              ? () => handleCreateRandomHexColor()
              : () => handleCreateRandomRGBColor()
          }style={{
            width: "100w",
            height: "100vh",
            background: {color},
        }}>
            <button onClick={() => setTypeOfColor("hex")}>Create HEX Color</button>
            <button onClick={() => setTypeOfColor("rgb")}>Create RGB Color</button>
            {/* <button onClick={handleCreateRandomColor}> Generate Random Color </button> */}
            <div 
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          color: "#fff",
          fontSize: "60px",
          marginTop: "50px",
          flexDirection  :'column',
          gap :'20px'
        }}>

                <h3>{typeOfColor === "rgb" ? "RGB Color" : "Hex Color"} </h3>
                <h1> {`${color}`}</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


Isn't there a comma missing in }style={{?

There was a comment left while this was in Staging Ground that got deleted when the question was posted.  It said you should use rgb(${r},${g}, ${b}) instead of just (${r},${g}, ${b}).

The syntax you've provided has a minor issue with the background property.
 <div
  onClick={
    typeOfColor === "hex"
      ? () => handleCreateRandomHexColor()
      : () => handleCreateRandomRGBColor()
  }
  style={{
    width: "100w",
    height: "100vh",
    background: color,
  }}
></div>


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
